# Automation of Windows Phone Application with Selenium and Appium

Tags: java, selenium, appium

I have an android application. I have automated it with Selenium and Appium. I wrote the scripts in Java language.

Now I want to automate the same application in Windows Phone platform. AFAIK, *Appium supports Android and IOS platform only.*

Is there any way I can automate Windows Phone application so that I can reuse the same test automation suite I built for Android application? Specifically I want one test suite that will test both android and windows phone application by changing only properties or something else those are concerned.

**Note:** I found an open source framework [Winium](https://github.com/2gis/Winium). Though it automates windows application, I would not prefer it because I can not reuse my test automation suite I built for Android application. I just don't want to write same scripts again, rather reusing the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can not automate Windows Phone application with Appium. You can try Xamarin (not open source).

Comment: Will I be able to use the java written scripts or I have to rewrite everything?

Comment: I guess you need to rewrite your scripts according to windows phone automation tool.